Perfect gas relation in differential form
I have a problem to understand the transformation of the perfect gas relation:
$$ \rho\cdot R\cdot T = P $$
into its differential form:
$$\frac {dp}{p} = \frac {d{\rho}}{\rho} + \frac {d{T}}{T}$$

How this transformation was done?
What does, in example $$ \frac {d{\rho}}{\rho} $$ mean?

Many thanks for all your replies.
Lukasz

Manifestly, the differential form is not derived from your first equation, as it contains temperature.

You can start from general ideal gas law :
$$ \tag 1 p = \rho \frac RMT$$
Now differentiate both sides,
$$\tag 2 dp = \frac RMd(\rho T) = \frac RM \left(\rho dT+Td\rho\right) $$
Divide both sides by $\rho$ of 2 eq.:
$$ \tag 3  \frac {dp}{\rho} = \frac RM\left(dT+T\frac{d\rho}{\rho}\right)$$
Now divide both sides of (3) by $T$ :
$$ \tag 4 \frac {dp}{\rho T} = \frac RM\left(\frac{dT}{T}+\frac{d\rho}{\rho}\right)$$
Yet we need to multiply both sides by $M/R$ :
$$\tag 5 \frac {M}{\rho RT}\times dp = \frac{dT}{T} + \frac{d\rho}{\rho}$$
Final fact is to acknowledge that first multiplicand in the left side of equation is just $1/p$, so :
$$ \tag 6 \boxed{ \frac{dp}{p} =  \frac{dT}{T} + \frac{d\rho}{\rho}}$$
And it means that relative increase of pressure is proportional to the sum of relative increase of temperature and (relative increase of) gas density.
Say you have increased gas temperature by $20\%$ and increased gas density by $10\%$ also. Hence your gas pressure will increase by $20\%+10\%=30\%$ percentage.
Hope that helps !

The second equation is the logarithmic form, and it is a good thing to know how to do. Take the natural log of both sides:
ln$\rho$ + ln R + ln T = ln p
Then take the differential ( d ln x = dx/x) to get the second equation, remember R is a constant so its differential is zero.
